# Photoshop Vs Fireworks

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-fireworks

What are the benefits of using one over the other. I know Fireworks better then photoshop but the general de-facto out there is photoshop. What makes Photoshop better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fireworks appears to be a product that Adobe picked up when it purchased Macromedia. It focuses on image creation mainly for online use (web, mobile and applications). Photoshop has more features. For people creating mainly online content, Fireworks probably has most/all the features they need and probably suits their workflow better than Photoshop. It's horses for courses.

From the [Adobe Fireworks FAQ](http://www.adobe.com/products/fireworks/faq/):

**Q: What's the relationship between Fireworks and Adobe Photoshop® software?**

**A:** Adobe Photoshop is the industry standard for digital imaging, with a broad array of features and functionality used by photographers, graphic designers, web designers, and many other creative professionals. While Fireworks does have some overlapping functionality, its vector and bitmap toolset is made for designers and developers who need features for wireframing, comping, prototyping, and creating optimized images for the web, mobile, and application interfaces. Fireworks imports and exports PSD files with high fidelity for smooth workflows between applications.